# How to merge multiple rows of timestamps and objects into line items for data pre-processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Hi Stack Overflow community!

As you can see from the screenshot below, I have a dataframe of crimes in my neighbourhood, which has multiple timestamps and types of crime for each day. 
[image: dataframe]

I am trying to create additional dataframe by merging the timestamps of the same date as well as converting and merging type of crimes (type = object) into integer format. Hence each day will be a line item. I also want to add a new column to show the results of data pre-processing based on the number of crimes per day. My goal is to create a new dataframe as shown below:

```
                 Crimes   Crime level
    2018-01-01   7        High
    2018-01-02   3        Medium  
    2018-01-03   2        Low 

    ... and so on
```

For 'Crime level' column, I was going to use the following code to the results of data pre-processing:

```
    new_df['Crime level'] = np.where(abs(new_df['Crimes'])>5, 'High',
                            np.where(abs(new_df['Crimes'])>2,'Medium','Low'))
```

What would be the best approach to achieve all these? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post you origin data by text? So we can just use `pd.read_clipboard()` to obtain the demo data.

Comment: FIY, the data you gives allows us to identify where the crimes happened (in this case Kits, Vancouver, BC) and it is possible to google to get the exact address as you give the lat and long. I don't know if they are original data or even if they are easy to find for anybody who is not working for the police/justice but I would suggest to not share these informations on a public website if they are from internal data sources. especially as your question is not related to these columns :)

Comment: @Dawei Can you please explain how to post the origin data by text? Is it just simple copy and paste in between? <pre></pre> Please advise :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Ben.T! I got this information from data catalogue of city of Vancouver, which is open for public. But I definitely understand your concern and I may reupload the screenshot. Thank you again for your feedback!

Comment: @ShawnS.Choi I'm surprised that such information are shared by the city, I would be annoyed to know that if I report a break into my house, it can be found on the city website... anyway, hope you will ge the answer you need :)

Comment: @Ben.T The raw data is the problem. In Japan, there are some city have the _Crime Map_, but it is just a mesh summarized map, not the raw point data.

Comment: @ShawnS.Choi You can `print(df)`, and copy the result.

Comment: @Dawei Thank you so much for the tip! I will keep this in mind for the future posting! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not related to the columns, you can solve it by just using the index.
At first, group your data just by each day.

```
# I created a demo df
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).count()
print(grouped)
```

```
            CRIME
2019-01-01      2
2019-01-02      5
2019-01-03      20
2019-01-04      2
2019-01-05      1
```

Then cut `CRIME` column into different levels.

```
grouped['Crime level'] = pd.cut(grouped.CRIME, 
                                bins=[0,2,5,100], 
                                labels =["Low","Medium","High"])
print(grouped)
```

The `pd.cut` operation cuts `CRIME` column into 3 intervals `(0,2], (2,5], (5,100]`, and assigns the labels `["Low","Medium","High"]` to each interval.

```
            CRIME Crime level
2019-01-01      2         Low
2019-01-02      5      Medium
2019-01-03     20        High
2019-01-04      2         Low
2019-01-05      1         Low
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you so much for all your helps and guidance on this @Dawei! Really appreciate it so so much! :)